# oracle hierarchical query given nodes and level

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a recursive table which contains item code and their parents.

**Table**

```
items
(
item_code   varchar2(40),
item_parent varchar2(40) 
)
```

**Problem**

When I specify the level and items in the query, I want the item's parents to be retrieved to the specified level in the query. Instead, when I specify the level only the items in this level return.

I want to retrieve the items from level 1 to the specified level.

**Example**

```
select item_parent 
from items
where level=3 and item code between  item_code and item_code
```

I want all the item from level 1 to level 3 including the item in the select statement
not only the item in level 3.